# Home country address or U.S address in DS 160 form for H4?

Tags: immigration

My husband's H1 B is approved and H1B status starts on Oct 1st, 2017. I'm planning to travel to India (home country)in November. In the form DS 160 for H4 visa, should I enter my home country address or my current US address? Also, when asked for "spouse's address", should I write his Indian home address or our current U S  address?